# Java recursion doesn't return all values

Tags: java, recursion

I have two columns in a table called `Folder and Parent.` And in my service I have a method called `FolderService.getAllParents(s)` - where `(s)` is a string. However a folder can also be in the parent column and I m trying to do a recursive formula to get all the folders and their respective parents. 
For example `Documents (parent)` and `Film (folder)` also `Film (parent)` and `Reviews(folder)` ,`Reviews(parent)` and `name(folder)` and so on. I want to get all the parents and folder according to the string searched. Here's the recursive formula that i m stuck on:

```
public ArrayList<String>  getParents(String s){
     ArrayList<String> mn = new  ArrayList<String>();
    for(FolderManager y:FolderService.getAllParents(s)){
        if(y.getParent().isEmpty()){
            mn.add(y.getFolder());
            return mn;
            }else{

                return getParents(y.getFolder());
            }
    }
    return mn;
}
```

I m not getting any errors but I m only getting till

`Documents (parent) - Film (folder)  Film (parent) - Reviews(folder)`

Comment: What's to do with Spring? What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it again.

Comment: In your for Loop you're returning something instead of adding the results to mn and continue with the loop. Maybe instead of using return getParents you should use mn.addAll(getParents)

Comment: In your loop you should `addAll()` to get all values that get added in the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if I understood you correctly, your FolderService.getAllParents() will always return one object (because one child can have only one parent, isn't it?).
Then I don't think recursion is needed here. It can be done with a simple loop:

```
List<String> getParents(FolderManager fm) {
    List<String> parents = new ArrayList<>();
    while (fm.getParent() != null) {
        parents.add(fm.getParent().getFolder());
        fm = fm.getParent();
    }
    return parents;
}
```